# How can I remove an object from an array if I know the value of one field of the object?

Tags: javascript

I tried to find out some good examples but SO seems to have mainly examples from 4-5 years ago and I would like to use a solution that would work using modern browser capabilities.

Ihave an array of test objects:

```
 var tests;
```

Each test object contains a `testId`.

How can I remove test object with `testId = 25` from the array `tests`. I was thinking of a for loop but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer depends on whether you know in advance whether there's at most one match, or potentially more than one (and in the latter case whether you want to remove all of them or just the first)

**Removing all matches**

The "simplest" way is to use `filter`, although strictly that produces a new array without the matching element:

```
tests = tests.filter(function(e) {
    return e.testId !== 25;
});
```

This is OK, unless other code is holding a reference to the original array.

Modifying the array safely "in-place" still appears to require a combination of a `for` loop with `.splice`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; ) {   // nb: deliberate .length test
    if (tests[i].testId === 25) {
        tests.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

The "safely" caveat is because the functional methods of iterating through an entire array will get confused if the current element in the array is removed.  That is not a concern in the "first match" methods shown below.

**Removing first (or only) match**

The plain `for` method is still pretty simple (and probably most efficient, too!)

```
for (var i = 0, n = tests.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (tests[i].testId === 25) {
        tests.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

The `.some` method per Johan's answer can iterate through an array and then exit on first match (although some may object on philosophical grounds to a boolean predicate function also mutating the array):

```
var didRemove = tests.some(function(e, i, a) {
    if (e.testId === 25) {
        a.splice(i, 1);
        return true;   // causes the loop to exit
    }
});
```

In ES6-draft there's [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), which is a generalisation of `.indexOf`:

```
var index = tests.findIndex(function(e) {
    return e.testId === 25;
});
if (index >= 0) {
    tests.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: As I am using modern browsers could the for loop be replaced with a foreach and a function? I will be using IE10 and above so not sure about the ES6 findIndex.  How could your last example be done with a .indexOf ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ I wouldn't, because mutating the array within a `forEach` call requires special care.  In particular, the array indexes after the `splice` will have changed, probably causing the following iterations to fail.

Comment: @SamanthaJ `.indexOf()` isn't a solution here because it only tests for entire object equality (which in this case means reference identity, not "value equality") and can't just test one field of the given object.   There's a polyfill available for the `.findIndex` function at the link above.

Comment: @SamanthaJ to elaborate on the `.forEach` issue - if on the first iteration `tests[0]` is removed, there's no way to tell `.forEach` to revist the "new" `tests[0]` instead of jumping to `tests[1]`.   That's why my plain `for` version above doesn't increment `i` if a match is found.    That said, if there's at most one match then this doesn't matter.

Comment: If you don't mind can you spend just a couple of minutes telling me how I could use the polyfill. After that I think the answer will be really good.

Comment: @SamanthaJ just include the given code somewhere in your JS some place before you try to use the `.findIndex` function.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to loop through all objects and splice a matching object out of the array.

Instead of forEach I use some (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Because with the some method you can "break" the loop by returning true so that you don't need to go through all objects if a match has been found.

```
tests.some(function(testObject, index) {
    if (testObject.testId === 25) {
        tests.splice(index, 1);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Or wrap it in a function

```
var removeObjectById = function(id) {
    tests.some(function(testObject, index) {
        if (testObject.testId === id) {
            tests.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

removeObjectById(25)
```

Comment: The `.some` solution is short, although actually modifying the array in a "test callback" makes me go "ewwww"!

Comment: That said, I've included this in my answer too, with the caveat that this method is only applicable in the "remove first" case - it's no use in the "remove all" variant.

Comment: So you don't like the solution but you have no problem using the answer as your own without giving credit? Nice job man.

Comment: It's a small part of my answer, and I did just give you credit here in your comments